# How to handle exceptions with Optional.orElseGet() properly

Tags: java, exception, option-type

I want to call an endpoint which takes a string as a parameter and returns some status, but the thing is, sometimes I need to call this endpoint a second time if the first call with the the initial param fails.

I.e. service `A` calls service `B` with `returnId="123"`, but service `B` returns 404, then I want to call service `B` again with `id="abc"`. (this way it is guaranteed I will have some status.)

I was wondering if I can do this with Optionals and not with a lot of try/catch and if/else blocks.

Here is what I have:

```
private String fetchStatus(Order order) {
    var status = Optional.ofNullable(order.getReturnId())
        .map(returnId -> getStatus(order.returnId))
        .orElseGet(() -> getStatus(order.getId()));

    log.info("Current status: {}", status);
    return status;
}

private String getStatus(String id) {
    try {
        return externalService.getOrderStatus(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to fetch status for order.", e);
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that if the service `B` (externalService) returns a 404 not found, my code never tries to call the alternative (`orElseGet`).

What is that I am getting wrong and not understanding properly?

Comment: AFAIK you can not avoid using `try`/`catch` blocks when doing functional, except if you are using a specific wrapper (such a the VAVR's `Try`).
Usually, functional programming does not matches well with exceptions and prefers "error signals" (which VAVR `Try` exactly is).

Comment: @sp00m then "how to do I execute it when an exception occurs" is probably a better question title.

Comment: I think your question title is fine as is. The confusion is that Optional is not about dealing with exceptions, but with null values. But if an exception plays the same role as "return null" (e.g. "throw NotFoundException"), then I guess it could make sense to use Optional here, as shown in Antoniossss' answer. Otherwise, a good old try/catch should do. I think I would ideally have `externalService#getOrderStatus(...)` return an Optional directly instead of throwing an exception in the case the order status is not found, which would allow you to flatMap over it in `#fetchStatus(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to have `externalService#getOrderStatus(...)` return an `Optional<String>` instead of throwing an exception, which would make `#fetchStatus(...)` look like the following:

```java
private String fetchStatus(Order order) {
    var status = Optional.ofNullable(order.getReturnId())
        .flatMap(externalService::getOrderStatus)
        .or(() -> externalService.getOrderStatus(order.getId()))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("should not happen according to your question"));
    log.info("Current status: {}", status);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up actually doing this!

Answer (score 2):

Return `null` instead of throwing exception so your `Optional.ofNullabe` will kick in.

```
private String getStatus(String id) {
    try {
        return externalService.getOrderStatus(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //log something so you knwo what happened
        return null;
    }
```

If that is a good approach in general, is another story.

Comment: I'd `catch (NotFoundException e) { log + return null } catch (Exception e) { rethrow via runtime exception }`, or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss, but I found the approach from sp00m somewhat better.